# Cloud Generator No More?

Tags: add-on

New to blender here.
I see some really cool images and tutorials showing a cloud generator add-on that looks volumetric.
Apparently it used to come with Blender though I see it is no longer in add-ons.
I can try to install it, and it shows up in add-ons, but then the tutorials show it being used through the Tools shelf which no longer looks anything like it used to.
Does the changes to the tool shelf mean this addon is no longer functional?

Comment: Most addons that lived in the 'Tools' panel now live in the 'UI' properties panel. You can open the panel by pressing the 'n' key from the Viewport.

Answer (score 2):

The cloud generator has been removed from the [*Blender Add-ons Contrib*](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) repository by commit [`rBACf439379cf637af05bec87e2ee0273dd2b2b43d6b`](https://developer.blender.org/rBACf439379cf637af05bec87e2ee0273dd2b2b43d6b) because it wasn't maintained and therefore not updated for Blender 2.8x.